# Automatic slideshow buttons timing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have created my first attempt at an automatic slideshow and the slideshow itself works how intended. However I have tried to create buttons on the bottom which can be clickable to display a particular image in the slideshow. The problem I am having is that when a button is pressed, the timer does not restart on the new image and so at times there are multiple images showing up. How to I resolve this? Thanks.

```
<div>
  <img id="img1" class="mySlides" src="images/Flyer2015.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img2" class="mySlides" src="images/1400.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img3" class="mySlides" src="images/TechtextilFlyer.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img4" class="mySlides" src="images/901.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img5" class="mySlides" src="images/2014.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img6 "class="mySlides" src="images/Flyer2014.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>


<script>
var myIndex = 0;
var currImageId;

carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) } {
   x[i].style.display = "none";  
}

myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1;}    
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
currImageId = myIndex;
setTimeout(carousel, 3500); // Change image every 3.5 seconds

</script>
</div>

<div style="min-width: 100%; padding: 0px 15px 5px 25px;">
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt1" onclick="changeimage('img1')"></button>
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt2" onclick="changeimage('img2')"></button>
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt3" onclick="changeimage('img3')"></button>
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt4" onclick="changeimage('img4')"></button>
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt5" onclick="changeimage('img5')"></button>
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt6" onclick="changeimage('img6')"></button>
</div>

<script>
function changeimage(newImageId) {
document.getElementById("img" + currImageId).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(newImageId).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Sorry if this doesn't display right. I am inexperienced on this site.

Comment: I already see a syntax error : `carousel` function is not closed by a curly brace `}`

Comment: `setTimeout` is not `setInterval`. It's not a carousel of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the timer first in order to implement it correctly. Make a global variable and assign timeout function to that variable and when you are clicking on the button, simply clear the timer and start it again. Something like following

```
var timer = null; //global var i.e. outside the function scope
....
timer = setTimeout(carousel, 3500); //just assign this function to this variable
..
```

and when you click on button, first clear the timeout like following

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

and then add it again

```
timer = setTimeout(carousel, 3500);
```

So the final code would look like following

```
<div>
  <img id="img1" class="mySlides" src="images/Flyer2015.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img2" class="mySlides" src="images/1400.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img3" class="mySlides" src="images/TechtextilFlyer.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img4" class="mySlides" src="images/901.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img5" class="mySlides" src="images/2014.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img id="img6 "class="mySlides" src="images/Flyer2014.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>


<script>
  var myIndex = 0;
  var timer = null;
  var currImageId;

  carousel();

  function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) } {
      x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }

    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1;}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      currImageId = myIndex;
      timer = setTimeout(carousel, 3500); // Change image every 3.5 seconds
</script>
</div>

<div style="min-width: 100%; padding: 0px 15px 5px 25px;">
  <button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt1" onclick="changeimage('img1')"></button>
  <button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt2" onclick="changeimage('img2')"></button>
  <button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt3" onclick="changeimage('img3')"></button>
  <button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt4" onclick="changeimage('img4')"></button>
 <button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt5" onclick="changeimage('img5')"></button>
<button class="bannerbuttonstyle" id="bt6" onclick="changeimage('img6')"></button>
</div>

<script>
  function changeimage(newImageId) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    document.getElementById("img" + currImageId).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(newImageId).style.display = "block";
    timer = setTimeout(carousel, 3500);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have Added the variable and assigned the function to it. however I am not sure where to put the two timeout functions within my script for it to work.

Comment: the first one remains the same, just assign it to "timer" variable , i.e. change setTimeout(carousel, 3500); // Change image every 3.5 seconds 
to
timer = setTimeout(carousel, 3500); // Change image every 3.5 seconds

and the clearTimeout(timer) would be called on first line on the function changeimage(newImageId) and on last line, call again timer function like 

timer = setTimeout(carousel, 3500);